# How to get base DSN for Active directory?

Tags: java, windows, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to access Active directory using LDAP. I dont have access to server directtly but am able to connect with AD server using `host name (abc.mydomain.net) + username and password and SSL certificate`.

But I'm not aware of Base DSN to query.

Is there any way I could I know Base DSN so that I could extract users from different groups using query ? How can I add my group name as well in Base DN ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What is "DSN"? Do you mean the distinguished name?

Comment: And how are you making these queries? Which programming language?

Comment: @GabrielLuci, Yes its a Base distinguished name and using java language

Comment: I see. It's usually referred to as the "base DN". The base DN of a domain is made up of each part of the domain name. So if the domain name is `abc.mydomain.net`, then the base DN is `DC=abc,DC=mydomain,DC=net`

Comment: @GabrielLuci, If I want to add "cn and ou" to this DN, how should I know the available value for "cn and ou" ?